# Проблема в регулярках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
  if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
} //возвращает uri

foreach ($routes as $controller => $method) {
  if (preg_match("~$controller~",$uri)){
    $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$controller~", $method, $uri);
    $segments = explode('/',$internalRoute);
    echo $internalRoute;
    print_r($segments);
    echo $uri;
  }
}
```

Вот сам массив роутов

```
   'product/([0-9]+)' => 'product/view/$1', 
   'catalog' => 'catalog/index',
   '' =>'mainPage/index',
   'test' =>'test/view'
```

При наборе в адресную строку test.com/index на выходе этого кода получаю

```
mainPage/indextmainPage/indexemainPage/indexsmainPage/indextmainPage/index  //$internalRoute

Array ( [0] => mainPage [1] => indextmainPage [2] => indexemainPage [3] => indexsmainPage [4] => indextmainPage [5] => index ) test/viewArray ( [0] => test [1] => view ) //$segments

index //$uri
```

Как исправить,чтобы он мне выдавал строку соответствующему роуту?
Как в шаблоне роутах ниже.

```
'product/([0-9]+)' => 'product/view/$1', 
   'catalog' => 'catalog/index',
   '' =>'mainPage/index',
   'test' =>'test/view'
```

Comment: `'' =>'mainPage/index',` чему угодно соответствует, если не ошибаюсь. Попробуйте указать границы строки в виде `'^$' =>'mainPage/index',`.

Comment: @Visman Указал,но это ничего не исправило.Проблема не в этом

Comment: Вы бы перед циклом добавили вывод `$uri` и отобразили бы его в вопросе.

Comment: @Visman готово,с uri всё в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) заменит найденный паттерн столько раз, сколько его встретит, если не указать в аргументах лимит.

Предлагаю вот такой вариант кода. Тоже без указания лимитов, но с указанием начала строки:

```
<?php
$routes = array(
   '^product/([0-9]+)' => 'product/view/$1',
   '^catalog' => 'catalog/index',
   '^$' =>'mainPage/index',
   '^index' =>'mainPage/index',
   '^test' =>'test/view',
);

$uri = 'product/1354';

foreach ($routes as $controller => $method) {
  if (preg_match("~$controller~",$uri)){
    $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$controller~", $method, $uri);
    $segments = explode('/',$internalRoute);
    echo "<pre>\n";
    echo 'uri="' . $uri . "\"\n\n";
    echo $internalRoute . "\n";
    print_r($segments);
    echo "</pre>\n";
  }
}
```

И результаты:

```
uri="product/1354"
product/view/1354
Array
(
    [0] => product
    [1] => view
    [2] => 1354
)
---
uri=""
mainPage/index
Array
(
    [0] => mainPage
    [1] => index
)
---
uri="index"
mainPage/index
Array
(
    [0] => mainPage
    [1] => index
)
```

Comment: всё бы хорошо,но при указании к примеру такого uri "test.com/test34/1354" роутер тоже срабатывает и выводит вот такое

    uri="test34/1354"
    test/view34/1354
   Array
   (
    [0] => test
    [1] => view34
    [2] => 1354
   )

Comment: добавить "$" в концы роутера,как я понял?

Comment: @ThreegunD, да, чтобы было полное соответствие строке запроса, а не ее началу.

Comment: Отлично теперь работает :)